# Aligning a string with correct amount of decimal places

Tags: python, formatting

I want the output to look like this:

```
Normal Pay:                $  450.00
```

I have written this:

```
normal_pay = 450.00
print(f"{'Normal Pay:':<27}${normal_pay:>8}")
```

This outputs:

```
Normal Pay:                $   450.0
```

I want to get `normal_pay` to print with two decimal places and be right-aligned keeping a field width of 8

I have tried below code to print two decimal places:

```
print(f"{'Normal Pay:':<27}${normal_pay:.2f:>8}")
```

But, this throws an error about the `:.2f`:

> ValueError: Invalid format specifier

Comment: The correct format specifier is `>8.2f`.

Comment: `print(f"{'Normal Pay:':<27}${normal_pay:>8.2f}")`